# Increment a value by 1 when button is clicked C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Have started a paper on C++ and have, what most experienced C++ programmers would call, a small problem...

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and coding in Visual C++ with .NET. I am trying to code the tiniest of applications that will add a new line into a textbox everytime a button is clicked. Adding new lines is simple enough, but I am wanting to add an incrementing integer with each line, e.g if I click on a button the first time, "This is line 1" gets added into the textbox, and on second click "This is line 2" gets added into the textbox. I am a little rusty on my programming and can't think of a looping structure that will enable this.

Here is the code (with some pseudocode) for the button's handler below:

```
private: System::Void addLine_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    int i = 0;
    if(button is clicked){
      listBox->Items->Add("This is line " + i);
      i++;
    }

}

Should output something like: 

This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
             .
             .
             .
This is line i
```

The name of my button is "addLine" and the name of the list box I want these lines to appear in is called "listBox".

Thanks in advance for helping this C++ noob :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is a local variable so it will loose its scope whenever the function exits. Either you need to declare i as `static` or make it as a class variable.

```
private: System::Void addLine_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    static int i = 0;
    if(button is clicked){
      listBox->Items->Add("This is line " + i);
      i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want to have access to it in different parts of the UI the member is the better option.

Comment: @TobiasLangner: Yes you are correct but seeing the problem i feel static would be more appropriate

Comment: I should have looked at my old Java code, I used to declare variables as static often.

Answer (score 0):

i needs to be a member of the class - otherwise the increment does not survive the call of the function.